# how to get the each record per group having maximum timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have the below table structure

**alert_details_status** table:

```
alertTypeId macId     timeStamp     is_notified  escalation_status  alertType
123         13446   1547722123000       true       completed          408
```

**alert_details** table:

```
basicid alertType   alertTypeId alertDescription    macId     timeStamp   companyId     alertName            alertCondition  unitType   channelType  alertValue expectedValue
1234     406            123         testalert       13446   1547722123000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50          60
1295     409            127         testalert       13448   1547722123000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1298     409            128         testalert       13448   1547722123000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1238     408            123         testalert       13446   1547722123000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1255     409            128         testalert       13448   1548135899000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1256     409            128         testalert       13448   1548135899000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
1251     408            123         testalert       13446   1548148705000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
```

If the `alert_details_status` table records has the `timestamp >30 minutes(compared to present time)` for each group of `alertTypeId`, `macId`, `alertType` having `is_notified` true and `escalation_status` completed then corresponding `alertTypeId`, `macId`, `alertType` having maximum timestamp for each record should be selected(maximum of one record per group eventhough timestamp is same for a group).

How to get the above result.
 I tried with the below query but it is returning nothing.Actually it should return 1251 basic id record as it is in `alert_details_status table having timestamp >30 min compared to present timestamp. So for that alertTypeId ,macId alertType it should return maximum of timestamp for a group having alertTypeId ,macId alertType(i,e 1251)`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT t1.*, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER( 
                   partition BY t1.alerttype, t1.alerttypeid, t1.macid 
                   ORDER BY t1.timestamp DESC) rn 
        FROM   [test].[dbo].[alertdetails] as t1
               RIGHT JOIN [test].[dbo].[alert_details_status] t2 
                      ON t1.macid = t2.macid 
                         AND t1.alerttypeid = t2.alerttypeid 
                         AND t1.alerttype = t2.alerttype 
                         AND t2.is_notified = 'true '
                         AND t2.escalation_status = 'completed' 
        WHERE  ((DATEDIFF(s, '1970-01-01', GETUTCDATE())-(t2.timeStamp/1000))/60)>4400 and t2.alerttypeid IS NULL  ) t 
WHERE  t.rn = 1
```

The result I wanted is :

```
  basicid   alertType   alertTypeId alertDescription    macId     timeStamp   companyId     alertName            alertCondition  unitType   channelType  alertValue expectedValue
    1251     408            123         testalert       13446   1548148705000   1234     test alert name            testalert   Centimeters   length        50.2        60.3
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to store date value as epoch dates? It is going to cause nothing but problems. You will constantly have to convert this to an actual datetime for any comparisons which will render any indexing on that column useless. And using datatype names for columns (timestamp) is not a good idea.

Comment: Are you positive the timestamp field is populated by date/time in UTC?

Comment: Also, in your where... "and t2.alerttypeid IS NULL" condition would be false in the provided data, so why do you expect a record to come back?

Comment: timestamp is int

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but if the date wasn't cast to UTC before turning into an int, it can't readily be compared with a UTC version